# System of differential equations with complex coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If you have a system of differential equations $\vec{x}'=L\vec{x}$ where the entries in $L$ may be complex, however its eigenvalues and components of the eigenvectors are all real can we solve it using the same method for when $L$ is all real? I haven't found a reason why not but I just want to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. A quick way to see this is to write $L = A + i B$, and $x = \xi + i \eta$. You will get the system $\xi' + i \eta' = A \xi - B \eta + i B \xi + i A \eta$, or
\begin{equation}
 (\xi' - A\xi + B\eta) + i (\eta' - B \xi - A \eta) = 0.
\end{equation}
Because a complex number is zero if and only of both its real part and its imaginary part are zero, you obtain the system
\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix} \xi \\ \eta \end{pmatrix}' = \begin{pmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \xi \\ \eta \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
So, a $n$ complex equations are equivalent to $2n$ real equations.